# Name of cartoon with iconic shoulder gadgets

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

In the 90s there was cartoon with a group of humans that had different shoulder gadgets, similar to what some Lego figures can wear (see image 1 but less armor like) but additionally had handles (similar to image 2 but frontal of the body).
These gadgets came with different colors and abilities. Like blue for also diving under water.
I think they also had a spacestation that could help them out / serve as meeting place.

Anyone knows more about it and what the name was?
For clarification these shoulder gadget are a central element.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be referring to
[Centurions](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0236893/)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosquad?
Seems a little off to be fair, but you're a little scarce on the details.

Comment: Thank you but I do not think so. Added some more clarification. Wish I could find the adequate lego piece but have no success in that direction as well.